# A question about billboard matrix convert

Tags: opengl, matrix, glsl

```
vec3 camPosInModelSpace = (inverse(mat_world) * vec4(worldCamPos, 1)).xyz;
vec3 axisZ = normalize(camPosInModelSpace);
vec3 axisY = axisZ.y > 0.999 ? vec3(0, 0, 1) : vec3(0, 1, 0);
vec3 axisX = normalize(cross(axisY, axisZ));
axisY = normalize(cross(axisZ, axisX));

mat4x4 rotate = mat4x4(vec4(axisX, 0), vec4(axisZ, 0), vec4(-axisY, 0), vec4(0, 0, 0, 1));

//vec3 vertexModelSpace = (transpose(rotate) * vec4(vPosition, 1)).xyz; // Here is my confused point
vertexModelSpace = axisX * vPosition.x + axisZ * vPosition.y + -axisY * vPosition.z;
gl_Position = mat_mvp * vec4(vertexModelSpace, 1);
```

As you can see, the billboard's GLSL code is very simple, but I just have a question about it, after I got the 3 axis under the model space, **why can't I use the matrix to convert the vertex(when I did that, only the Y-axis seemed works right)**, but when I used the tutorial's way, it works fine.
Please help me, I am really confused with this, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

OepnGL and GLSL is build with column-major as the default matrix layout in mind, consequently, `mat4 m; m[c][r]` is used to access the `r-`th row of `c`-th column and `m[c]` will return the `c`-th colum as `vec4`. Consistently to that, the matrix constructor uses the column vectors: `mat4 m(c0,c1,c2,c3)`, hence

> ```
> mat4x4 rotate = mat4x4(vec4(axisX, 0), vec4(axisZ, 0), vec4(-axisY, 0), vec4(0, 0, 0, 1));
> ```

will result in a matrix in mathematical notation:

```
axisX.x    axisZ.x  -axisY.x    0
axisX.y    axisZ.y  -axisY.y    0
axisX.z    axisZ.z  -axisY.z    0
   0          0         0       1
```

and therefore

> ```
> vertexModelSpace = (transpose(rotate) * vec4(vPosition, 1)).xyz;
> ```

is **not** equivalent to

> ```
> vertexModelSpace = axisX * vPosition.x + axisZ * vPosition.y + -axisY * vPosition.z;
> ```

but will actually use the transpose of that transform matrix, which happens to be the inverse for rotation matrices.

Comment: thank you for reply, it's my fault, I didn't make clear about my confused point, sorry about it, actually I can understand my matrix transform is not equivalent to another one, my confused point it, the matrix which I got(the transpose m), should be convert the vertex under model space to the new model space(just like we convert the normal or tangent to world space or tangent space), I think the matrix I got should convert the vertex from parent space(model space) to child space(new model space), but I can't get the correct result, if you know the reason, please teach me, thank you.